# Dot and colon meaning

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What does dot-colon `.:`

```
- .:/var/www/project:cached
```

mean in situation like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    image: php:7.1-fpm
    ports:
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/project:cached
```

Is this part of bash syntax or is it part of Docker syntax (haven't found any info on both).

Comment: Neither; it's just a string stored in the list associated with the key `volumes`. It's up to whoever is consuming the YAML file to decide what to do with the string `.:/var/www/project:cached`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- `.` is used for "current directory"
- `:` is used to separate the `host`'s path from `container`'s path. (Each volume uses a `source` path for the host and a `destination` path for the container).
- `:cached` seems to be a caching option for [docker-for-mac](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#caching-options-for-volume-mounts-docker-for-mac)

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3):

> #### Short syntax
>
> Optionally specify a path on the host machine (`HOST:CONTAINER`), or an access mode (`HOST:CONTAINER:ro`).
>
> You can mount a relative path on the host, that expands relative to the directory of the Compose configuration file being used. Relative paths should always begin with `.` or `..`.

Answer (score 6):

As per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3):

> Optionally specify a path on the host machine (`HOST:CONTAINER`), or an
>   access mode (`HOST:CONTAINER:ro`).
>
> You can mount a relative path on the host, that expands relative to
>   the directory of the Compose configuration file being used. Relative
>   paths should always begin with `.` or `..`.

The `.` is a directory where docker-compose file is located. It will be mounted to the path after the colon.